# Create column based on number of occurences of satisfied criteria in sequence in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

I have a dataset similar to the following:

```
import pandas as pd

date0 = ["2020-01-31"] * 3
date1 = ["2020-02-28"] * 3
date2 = ["2020-03-31"] * 3

date = date0 + date1 + date2
acc = ["A", "B", "C"] * 3
val = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": date, "account": acc, "value": val})
```

The goal is to create a new column called "output" which counts the occurrences of the binary column "value" based on "account" over a given time series. If the column "val" shows three (or N) 1's in a row, the output column is a 1, otherwise it is a 0.

For the dataset above, this would yield:

```
output = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
df["output"] = output
```

Furthermore, if the 4th iteration in the time series is a 0, then the sequence begins again. Naturally, if the 4th iteration is a 1, then the output is a 1.

The dataset below shows that account "A" has satisfies the criteria after just the first 3 months, then the account reverts back, starting the cycle again. Account "B" satisfies the criteria from month 2-4, etc. This is part of a large simulation so a vectorised solution would be ideal.

```
date3 = ["2020-04-30"] * 3
val = [0, 1, 1]
acc = ["A", "B", "C"]
output = [0, 1, 0]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"date": date3, "account": acc, "value": val, "output": output})

df3 = pd.concat([df,  df2])
```

Comment: You have only one value per month per account?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one value per month per account and you have no missing dates, you can use `groupby_rolling`:

```
df['output'] = (df.groupby('account').rolling(3)['value']
                  .sum().eq(3).astype(int).droplevel(0))
print(df)

# Output
         date account  value  output
0  2020-01-31       A      1       0
1  2020-01-31       B      0       0
2  2020-01-31       C      0       0
3  2020-02-28       A      1       0
4  2020-02-28       B      1       0
5  2020-02-28       C      0       0
6  2020-03-31       A      1       1
7  2020-03-31       B      1       0
8  2020-03-31       C      1       0
```

For your second example:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df,  df2], ignore_index=True)  # <- ignore_index=True
df3['output2'] = (df3.groupby('account').rolling(3)['value']
                     .sum().eq(3).astype(int).droplevel(0))
print(df3)

# Output
          date account  value  output  output2
0   2020-01-31       A      1       0        0
1   2020-01-31       B      0       0        0
2   2020-01-31       C      0       0        0
3   2020-02-28       A      1       0        0
4   2020-02-28       B      1       0        0
5   2020-02-28       C      0       0        0
6   2020-03-31       A      1       1        1
7   2020-03-31       B      1       0        0
8   2020-03-31       C      1       0        0
9   2020-04-30       A      0       0        0
10  2020-04-30       B      1       1        1
11  2020-04-30       C      1       0        0
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a larger dataset for testing, and it's doing quick and well.

I kept intermediate columns I create in order for you to see what's going on.

```py
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

date0 = ["2020-01-31"] * 6
date1 = ["2020-02-28"] * 6
date2 = ["2020-03-31"] * 6

date = date0 + date1 + date2
acc = ["A", "B", "C"] * 6
val = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": date, "account": acc, "value": val})

start = time.time()

w=[]
N = df['account'].nunique() # N=3 in your example
for i in range(N):
    S = df["value"][i::N]
    w.append(swv(S, N).sum(axis=1))
df['w'] = np.pad(np.array(w).flatten('F'), (N*2, 0), mode='constant')
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1]

df['mod'] = (df.groupby('account')
               .cumsum(numeric_only=True)
               .mod(N))["value"]

df["output"] = df['w'] + df['mod']
df["output"] = (df["output"].where((df['w'] + df['mod']).eq(df['w']) & df['w'].eq(N), 0)
                            .astype(bool)
                            .astype(int))

end = time.time()
print("time_speed : ", end - start)
print("df : ", df)
```

**Result**

```
time_speed :  0.002397298812866211
df :  
    date       account  value  w  mod  output
0   2020-01-31       A      1  0    1       0
1   2020-01-31       B      0  0    0       0
2   2020-01-31       C      0  0    0       0
3   2020-01-31       A      1  0    2       0
4   2020-01-31       B      1  0    1       0
5   2020-01-31       C      0  0    0       0
6   2020-02-28       A      1  3    0       1
7   2020-02-28       B      1  2    2       0
8   2020-02-28       C      1  1    1       0
9   2020-02-28       A      1  3    1       0
10  2020-02-28       B      0  2    2       0
11  2020-02-28       C      0  1    1       0
12  2020-03-31       A      1  3    2       0
13  2020-03-31       B      1  2    0       0
14  2020-03-31       C      0  1    1       0
15  2020-03-31       A      1  3    0       1
16  2020-03-31       B      1  2    1       0
17  2020-03-31       C      1  1    2       0
```

**Explanation**

- column `w` : 3-windowing with numpy starting at row 6 in the example (previous is not necessary like you need 3 consecutives `1`). You have 3 consecutives `1` when window sum is `3`.
- column `mod` : `cumsum` modulo value (introduction of a cyclicality)

With `cumsum` modulo value you have `0` in the column `mod` for `0%3` and `3%3`.

When you add `w` and `mod` columns you indeed filter out rows with `0%3` like `0` in column `w` added to `0` in column `mod` give `0`.

On the other hand `3` in column `w` added to `0` in column `mod` give `3` (which is N value in the example)